# Tuple<string, int> JSON to pass to wcf

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, json

Anyone know how to pass this via Json.

Tried doing something like

```
var data = { Item1: "test", Item2: 5 };
var JSONdata = $.toJSON(data);
```

However that did not work.  Although simply changing wcf to expect an object with two properties such as Item1 and Item2 will work.

This is in asp.net

Thanks in advance.

Here is example I'm using... I'll trim it a bit to make it easier to read:

```
function Post(data, url)
{
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(return){},
  dataType: 'json'
});
}

var data = { Item1: "test", Item2: 5 };
var JSONdata = $.toJSON(data);
Post(data, url);
```

Comment: how are you calling your WCF service?

Comment: doing it via jquery... fairly straight forward. works very well with all the classes that have named properties. running into a difficulty with generics in this case a Tuple.

Comment: please post an example of how thats done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because Tuples don't have a default (no-argument) constructor.

> Although simply changing wcf to expect an object with two properties such as Item1 and Item2 will work.

I strongly suggest doing this. Having a defined Data Transfer Object class is good practice. It will allow you to name your properties more clearly, which makes things easier to maintain and reduces the likelihood of introducing bugs. For example, it'd be really easy to accidentally write:

```
var data = { Item1: 5, Item2: "test" };
```

... while you'd be far less likely to write:

```
var data = { Title: 5, ID: "test" };
```

Comment: I ended up doing exactly this anyway. Thanks for clearing it up for me.